# Eclipse plugin GAE, can't configure SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I have problems setting up google app engine SDK in Eclipse with Google app engine plugin, focused on programming PHP aps, not java aps. PHP doesent have a SDK, [its inside GAE SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/download).

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1
- java version "1.8.0_111"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
- Python 2.7.10
- google-cloud-sdk-137.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
  app-engine-php " "
  app-engine-php-darwin 2015.11.16
  app-engine-python 1.9.40
  bq 2.0.24
  bq-nix 2.0.24
  core 2016.12.06
  core-nix 2016.12.06
  gcloud 
  gsutil 4.22
  gsutil-nix 4.22
- Eclipse for PHP Developers
  Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
  Build id: 20161007-1200

But when i try to locate GAE SDK y get this error and can't start a new project cause this is not set.

[Failed to initialize app engine SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgU1x.png)

Please help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up the new Google Cloud SDK with the App Engine Java SDK. They are not the same thing. The old legacy GPE plugin you're using expects the [App Engine Java SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download).